# Is ( (A⊆B) & (B⊆A) ) → A = B a theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(It's probably important to state that I'm not a trained mathematician. Apologies if this question is too naive.)

The formula in question is $((A \subseteq B)  \And (B \subseteq A))\rightarrow(A=B))$.

This formula is a plausible formalisation of a purported proof by Thomas Hobbes, in his /Leviathan/, of the "co-extensiveness" of natural law and civil law.

It seems intuitively valid and I haven't been able to find any counterexamples. But I'd like to know with certainty that it's true, if it's true. Two questions follow from this:

1) /is/ it a theorem? if it is, what is its proof, if this proof is straightforward?

2) what kind of course-material would I have to master in order to produce such a proof myself? Is that course-material available on the internet?

(With regard to question two: of course I'm only asking about the /most advanced necessary/ material; I assume none of you can know exactly how backward I am from the evidence of this short post.)

Comment: Whether this is a theorem (and not an axiom), and how to prove it if it is, depends very much on which exact logic system and set theory you're using. It is _the_ standard way to prove two sets to be equal, though, so it's safe to assume that it is true in any case.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq A) \leftrightarrow A = B$?

Comment: Isn't it just the axiom of extensionality in the ZFC formulation?

Comment: If you are interested in logic and set theory (those two often go together), I recommend [A Mathematical Introduction To Logic](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Introduction-Logic-Second/dp/0122384520/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1527244999&sr=8-1&keywords=enderton) and [Elements of Set Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Set-Theory-Herbert-Enderton/dp/0122384407/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1527244999&sr=8-2&keywords=enderton), both by Enderton. I'll be honest, I didn't finish any of these books (planning to do so this summer), but, from what I read I can tell that they are very good.

Comment: By the way, [Mathoma](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCL_lVXCyzqBb2Xc8CrvPENg/featured) has very good series about set theory. Check it out, you may like it.

Comment: You can see S.Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) and part of [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a theorem, and the proof is just very simple set theory:

The set relation $A\subset B$ is equivalent to the statement at the level of elements that $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$. Similarly, $A=B$ means that $x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B$.

To prove your theorem we need to show $x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B$, given the assumptions $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$. 
Suppose that $x\in A$. Since $A\subset B$, we have $x\in B$. Thus we have proved $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$. From the other assumption we prove in the same way that $x\in B \Rightarrow x\in A$. 
Since we have proved the implications in both directions, we have proved that $x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$, from our assumptions, i.e. that $A=B$.

Comment: The details of this are sensitive to the precise choices made for how to present axiomatic set theory, which varies from author to author. If you're going to be formal, you should not omit the quantifiers, so your definition of $A=B$ would be $\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B)$. But quite a number of authors consider $=$ to be a primitive symbol without a definition (but with specific logical rules governing it), and take $\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B)\to A=B$ to be an _axiom_, the Axiom of Extensionality.

Comment: Yet others take $A=B$ to mean $\forall x(A\in x\leftrightarrow B\in x)$ and write the axiom of extensionality as $\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B)\leftrightarrow A=B$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don’t know enough about this so I’m sure you are right, I intended this rather to show how one would carefully prove this from the “naive” perspective the questioner seemed to have (:

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did. I read your $\to$ as $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: The "naive-style" proof you offer in the third paragraph at least helps me unpack my intuition a little; so I'm accepting this answer, since (per the comment of @HenningMakholm) greater rigour depends on kinds of decision (about axiom choice) that I'm not atm equipped to assess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a theorem. It's proof is very simple.

$A \subseteq B$ means *every element of set A is in set B also*. $A \land B$ (you wrote conjunction symbol as $\&$, but I prefer $\land$) means *A is true and B is true*. If I say $A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$, I'm saying *every element of A is in B and every element of B is in A*. Clearly, this means that sets $A$ and $B$ have exactly same elements.

You used $\rightarrow$, but I'd use $\leftrightarrow$. $A \rightarrow B$ means *if A is true then B is also true*, but $A \leftrightarrow B$ means *if A is true than B is also true and if B is true then A is also true*.

Therefore, $A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A \leftrightarrow A = B$ means *if every element of A is in B and every element of B is in A, then A and B are equal, and if A and B are equal, then every element of B is in A and every element of A is in B*. If I used a right instead of a double arrow, then there would be a possibility that if $A = B$ is true $A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$ isn't true. In other words, $A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$ wouldn't need to be true for $A = B$ to be true.

Comment: For the advices on how to learn this, see my comments on the question.

Comment: I would change $A$ and $B$ in the part where you talk about $\leftrightarrow$, since those were the same letters the OP used for sets.

Comment: Presumably, though, $(A \leftrightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$, i.e. my formulation is not _false_ but is only not exhaustive (i.e. only shows one of two relations of logical dependency between the LHS and the RHS?

Comment: Well... it's not _absolutely_ false, since when the $A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$ is true, your definition is correct, but not necessarely when $A=B$ is true. We could say that it doesn't express the standard definition of set equality to the fullest. But, mathematics has extremely rigorous precision standards so your formulation *is* false because it isn't enough precise. But only if you want your definition of set equality to match the standard one. If the standard definition of set equality got replaced by your definition, a big part of set theory would fall apart.